# I cannot understand output order of the recursive function

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

I have the following code to construct a binery tree from a list. But I don't understand the order of the output. If I input [1,2,3] the output is [2,1,3]. I thought it should be [1,3,2]
Can anyone help me explain it... I can not think it through.

```
// Definition for a binary tree node.
// class TreeNode(object):
//    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
//        self.val = val
//         self.left = left
//         self.right = right
class Solution(object):
    
    def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums):
   
       
        def constructBST(l,r):
            if l>r:
                return None
            mid=(l+r)//2
            
            root = TreeNode(nums[mid])
          
            root.left=constructBST(l,mid-1)
            root.right=constructBST(mid+1,r)
           
            return root
        return constructBST(0,len(nums)-1)
```

Comment: your program has no output

Comment: you should have a tree with root node value 2, left node value 1 and right node value 3. But the order you print it out will determine your output.